# Move screen to the left with `xrandr`

Tags: linux, xorg, xrandr

I am using a smaller resolution than my laptop monitor, so that I get black bars on both sides (left and right).

Is it possible--with `xrandr`--to align the screen to the left, so that instead of 2 black bars on both sides, I get a single bigger one on the right?

Comment: Try to fill your screen? Check what resolution your laptop supports. Change it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MScLD8dFNwk

Comment: @arochester, I appreciate your help, but I'm aware that I can fill my screen. That has nothing to do with the question posted.

Comment: The black bar is produced by your hardware, not xrandr.

Comment: @IporSircer: but, can't xrandr tell the hardware to move the screen? I know it can stretch the output, etc., can it move the output?